# Exception in getting Image thumbnails in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, thumbnails

I am getting the thumbnail of an Image in the `doInBackground()` method of the `AsyncTask`. The problem is while running the `AsyncTask` if I cancel the `AsyncTask` using `cancel()`. I am getting a strange exception in the logcat. The app is not terminating but the logcat is showing the exception message.

**My doInBackground() is like below**

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String path = params[0];
        bitmap = getImageThumbnail(MainActivity.this,path);
        //Some cache mechanism
        return bitmap;
    }
```

**getImageThumbnail Method**

```
     public static Bitmap getImageThumbnail(Context context,String path) {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor ca = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{path}, null);
            if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) {
                int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                ca.close();
                //At this line I am getting exception
                Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                return thumbnail;
            }
            return ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dummy)).getBitmap();
        }
```

While the async task is in runnign state if I call the `asyncTask.cancel(true)` I am getting the below message in logcat

```
06-11 17:49:45.380    1600-1708/com.sample.appl V/MiniThumbFile﹕ Got exception checking file magic:
    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.checkOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:73)
            at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:161)
            at android.media.MiniThumbFile.getMagic(MiniThumbFile.java:161)
            at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:635)
            at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:1008)
            at com.appsforbb.common.filesystem.ImageUtils.getImageThumbnail(ImageUtils.java:55)
            at com.appsforbb.basic.filemanager.CacheImageView$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(CacheImageView.java:79)
            at com.appsforbb.basic.filemanager.CacheImageView$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(CacheImageView.java:58)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

How to avoid that exception??

Comment: why are you doing `ca.close();` two times ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I removed ca.close but still getting same result!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your cursor before creating your bitmap thumbnail, change your `getImageThumbnail` method to look like this:

```
public static Bitmap getImageThumbnail(Context context,String path) {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor ca = null;
            ca = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{path}, null);
            if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) {
                int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));

                //At this line I am getting exception
                Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                ca.close();
                return thumbnail;
            }
            return ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dummy)).getBitmap();
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is with closing come channel or socket. Can you please post your AsyncTask class?

Answer (score 0):

Use `asyncTask.cancel(false)` to cancel the async task. Then, check `isCancelled()` before calling `getImageThumbnail()` in your `doInBackground()`.

Your `doInBackground()` will now be:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String path = params[0];
    if(!isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = getImageThumbnail(MainActivity.this,path);
        //Some cache mechanism
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

You should also check `isCancelled()` before doing anything in `postExecute()`.

Comment: Its not working because the problem is at line bitmap = getImageThumbnail(MainActivity.this,path); While executing this line I am canceling the async task

Comment: Does the same problem you had occur when you cancel the async task and pass `false` to `AsyncTask.cancel()`?

Comment: No if I call AsyncTask.cancel(false) I won't get that exception why because if the async task is already started then if call cancel(false) it will not stop the async task.

Comment: When you call `AsyncTak.cancel(false)`, you should check `isCancelled()` in `doInBackground()` and `postExecute()`, return without doing anything if `isCancelled()` returns `true`